# Python. upper в цикле for делает одинаковые соседние буквы большими

Tags: python

В общем нужно каждую букву заданного слова сделать большой.Но почему то когда дело доходит до 2х рядом стоящих одинаковых букв, они обе становятся большими.Почему так происходит и как от этого избавится?
'HeLLo', 'HeLLo' => 'HeLlo', 'HelLo'

```
def wave(people):
    count = 0
    c = []
    for i in range(len(people)):
        c.append(people.replace(people[count],(people[count].upper())))
        count += 1
    return c

print(wave('Hello'))

['Hello', 'HEllo', 'HeLLo', 'HeLLo', 'HellO']
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Это и не для рядом стоящих так будет.
Происходит это потому, что вы в `replace(people[count],(people[count].upper()))` даёте команду заменить все буквы 'l' (чему соответствует и `people[2]` и `people[3]`) на `L`.

Исправить предложил бы так - используя индексы:

```
def wave(people):
    c = []
    for i in range(len(people)):
        c.append(people[:i] + people[i].upper() + people[i+1:])
    return c

print(wave('Hello'))  # Правильно: ['Hello', 'HEllo', 'HeLlo', 'HelLo', 'HellO']
```

Обратите внимание, что я убрал совершенно лишний `count` - у вас же итератор есть. Это в `While` подобный `count` был бы нужен.

Comment: Спасибо, как то не подумал об этом.

Answer (score 2):

Это для визуализации, если интересно будет.

```py
import time
word = 'hello'
for _ in range(3):
    print(word, end='')
    time.sleep(1)
    print('\b' * len(word), end='')

    for i in range(len(word)):
        print(word[:i] + word[i:].capitalize(), end='')
        time.sleep(1)
        print('\b' * len(word), end='')

print(word)
```

что до решения Вашей задачи то:

```py
word = 'hello'
wlist = [word[:i] + word[i:].capitalize() for i in range(len(word))]
# ['Hello', 'hEllo', 'heLlo', 'helLo', 'hellO']
```